# How manage two jQuery and c# event of one div?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a div like below I want to do some work when I click div:

1. with jQuery click I want to show another div that contain ListView (that must show messages) and by another click hide that div.
2. with C# click event I want to get Messages and bind to ListView

jQuery works but C# event does not work.

Another problem is that if I click div for second time the div will hide and I don't want bind messages

How should I do these works?

```
 <div id="div1" class="Message" runat="server" onclick="ShowMessage">
```

jquery code:(this works)

```
 $('#div1').click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($("#div2").is(":hidden")) {
                $("#div2").show(500);
            }
            else {
                $("#div2").hide(500);
            }

        });
```

and my code behind:(does not work)

```
protected void ShowMessage(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)//this will bind messages to ListView inside of div2
{
        using (MYEntities en = new MyEntities())
        {
            ///...
        }
}
```

Comment: div has no server side click event.

Comment: if i use other control like button.How should i solve that problem ?

Comment: You can do it with div click by calling a webmethod using ajax request that returns the message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using button then javascript click event of the button will get call and at the end just write return true then it will go to ServerSide click event of the button.

```
$('#btnClick').click(function(){
// your code
return true;
}

Protected void btnClick_Click()
{
}
```